# The order of expressions in an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between these (bCondition == NULL) and (NULL==bCondition)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854317/what-is-the-difference-between-these-bcondition-null-and-null-bcondition)
>   [Javascript minification of comparison statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256579/javascript-minification-of-comparison-statements)

Ive been writing my `if` statements like this:

```
if(variable1 === 1){}
if(variable2 > 10){}
if(variable3 == "a"){}
```

But I remember reading somewhere (unfortunately I cant find that page anymore), that `if` statements are better off written like this:

```
if(1 === variable1){}
if(10 < variable2){}
if("a" == variable3){}
```

Where you put the variable on the right hand side of the expression.

Is this correct? And, if so, can anyone shed any light on why this is correct? Also, does this apply to all programming languages, or just javascript?

TIA

Comment: Both are correct but the second is ugly.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xXkvA.jpg, from [this deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2430307/508666). For people who cannot see deleted stuff: `"Yoda Conditions"— using if(constant == variable) instead of if(variable == constant), like if(4 == foo). Because it's like saying "if blue is the sky" or "if tall is the man"`. A.k.a. fugly as hell :)

Comment: Both work, but apparently the second, uglier, option is better? Runs faster?

Comment: It does not run faster. It is uglier thus you slow down debugging and reading code

Comment: I think the second one is good for cases when you're comparing the result of a very long expression to a fixed value. E.g. `false === myObject.myOtherObject.veryLongMethodName(way, too, much, parameters)`

Comment: Yoda Conditions -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854317/what-is-the-difference-between-these-bcondition-null-and-null-bcondition

Comment: @Yoshi In this specific case please simply use `!(my...`

Comment: why second one is faster ?

Comment: @destroy Really? That's what you took from the example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1 === variable1` is same as the expression `variable1 === 1` written in Yoda notation**: constant listed on left hand side, variable on the right hand side.

The main reason why some programmers choose to use it is to avoid the common mistake of writing `if (a = 1)` where the programmer actually meant `if (a == 1)` or `if (a === 1)`. The following line of code will work but not as expected (`a` is assigned a value and `if` block will always get executed):

```
if (a = 1) {}
```

The same expression written the other way round will generate a syntax (or compile) error:

```
if (1 = a) {}
```

The programmer can immediately spot the error and fix it.

I do not like or use the Yoda notation. I try to keep my eyes open while coding.

** I am unable to find out the origin of this term.

Comment: origin of the term: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html

Answer (score 2):

Some people may prefer to reverse the order of values in the `if` cause the second form is more protective.
In fact if you miss to type an equal sign:

```
if (42 = myVar) { }
```

throws a syntax error at compile time, while

```
if (myVar = 42) { }
```

evaluates the completion value of the assignment expression, `42` in this case, that is a *truthy value* in JavaScript.

Anyway a similar error today can be easily spotted with tools such as [eslint](https://eslint.org/)... So there's no a real point for using first form.

Comment: This is hardly a good reason to use the less readable form.

Comment: the accepted answer to this question suggests otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854317/what-is-the-difference-between-these-bcondition-null-and-null-bcondition

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but the second one is ugly and I haven't really seen much of it. It's the same as say

> "If blue is sky"

instead of

> "if sky is blue"

. Can't recal where I have read it :).

Comment: [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) sets values at the first place in `if` clauses.

Comment: I tried. I noticed. Still looks like reading from right to left

Comment: I wonder why Closure Compiler uses "Yoda conditions"?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html defines this as "Yoda Conditions" and uses the "if blue is sky" example.

Comment: @Jimmery: I read somewhere (I think on Closure compiler's discussion forum) that `1 === somevar` compress better than `somevar === 1` and that is the _only_ reason.

Answer (score 0):

**=== :**

By definition, it's commutative, as it checks both objects are the same (same type, same value).

**== :**

== is more complex as there are conversions involved but [the specification makes it clear](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3) :

> A == B is equivalent to B == A, except in the order of evaluation of  A and  B

In other words, `==` is commutative.

This means you should simply use the less ugly and the most familiar to readers. That's the first one.